# How to combine properties of passed generic type

Tags: typescript, generics

If I have a type:

```
interface Item {
  id: string
  children: Array<Item>
}
```

How can I modify it to make it a generic such that it combines the properties of `Item` and the passed generic type `T`.

**Example:**

```
interface WithLabel {
   label: string
}

const item: Item<WithLabel> = {id: "x", label: "y", children: []};

console.log(`id=${item.id}, label=${item.label}`)
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure why you want `Item` to be generic here; just write `const item: Item & WithLabel = {...}`.  Could you motivate your question with an example for where that doesn't work for you?

Comment: typescript won't automatically blend things together at runtime either

Comment: @jcalz, I'm writing a tree component where `Item` will have some basic properties related to processing the tree item (`id`, `depth`, `parentId`) and then I want to pass other properties of generic type to the children component? Not sure if that is clear enough context?

And also I'm learning TypeScript so just wanted to understand how something like that would be possible, if at all.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL8bZm) meet your needs? (Note that I added a `children` property to `Item`; you might want to [edit] to do the same with your example code to motivate the generic and make it a [mre]).  If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Shall I write up an answer then? Or are you inclined to accept the existing one?

Comment: @jcalz, one question though, is it not possible to have the above with just something like `interface Item<T> { ... }` without having to declare a new `type` and combining through the `&` operator? Just curious.

Comment: Hey I asked you a question first. The answer to yours is: you will need a `type`; you can't have an `interface` unless all the property keys are statically known, and since you intend a value of type `Item<T>` to have property keys depending on `T`, then an interface is not possible.  So, let's try again: shall I write up an answer explaining this? Or are you inclined to accept the existing one and any changes should be suggested to that user?

Comment: @jcalz, I apologize must have missed it. You can write an answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: Okay, answered.  I also [edit]ed the question as I suggested; hope that's okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make `Item` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type of the form `Item<T>` where it has all the properties of `T`, then you'll need to change it to be a [`type` alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) instead of an [`interface` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces), and [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) your previous definition of `Item` with `T`:

```
type Item<T> = {
    id: string,
    children: Array<Item<T>> 
} & T;
```

The intersection of two types has all the properties of each type, so an `Item<T>` will have an `id` and `children` property as well as all the properties of `T`:

```
interface WithLabel {
    label: string
}

const item: Item<WithLabel> = {
    id: "x",
    label: "y",
    children: []
}; // okay

console.log(`id=${item.id}, label=${item.label}`) // okay
```

---

The reason it has to be a type alias and not an interface type is that interfaces are required to have *statically known keys*.  But some of `Item<T>`'s keys are only known once `T` is specified, so it cannot be an interface.  There are some differences between interfaces and type aliases, but in many situations they are interchangeable.  Whether this is actually a problem or not depends on your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABARQK6wJYHsQoDewKpKALgJ5yoCS5UEKAvESWR9gCYBcKM5AE7YQAcwA07DqUQALbABsugqCD4BBQYLCUAPPUYA+KSgC+wEyIaCAZklQB1bOVkAZMACMoCttLILPbz4BYTETcxNEfAEUZ0YWXz9Y3hQAIgAPVMkklACvBT5UyiyTDjlFZVU+AG0AXXCAbgsy6NwFKAA6BVxRAAoAA25mABJCOIgO7lNxXMCFEbGGCbzvU36ASgsI8Gh4exR1EBgAdyhBNhMqGhQDCF0AFUME4hzuYKERCVKycqUVNQOWh0+iWD0Mxg4phQADIUPcmpYQNY7MgUE4XO58ok-CsCvwPmFIc0ftFyLElnxbrp0W45k9WC8km80plsklcYVimy-L9KgC6o1iTJWu0uj0BkNRuNJlxprN8gtpbi1ptgKYgA)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You can define the types as follows:

```
interface BaaseeItem {
  id: string
}

type Item<T> = BaseItem & T;
```

and now this works as expected, with no type errors:

```
interface WithLabel {
   label: string
}

const item: Item<WithLabel> = { id: 'a', label: 'abc'};

console.log(`id=${item.id}, label=${item.label}`)
```